# Difference between allocation and initialisation

Tags: c

What is the difference between allocation and intialisation? How many times does the below variable x get allocated if there were an int and a static int?

```
int main(){
 int i = 2;
 int j;
 for(j = i; j < 20; j++){
   int x = 5;
   //static int x =5;
   printf("\n x = %d \n",x);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like school assignment.

Comment: @Yossarian Completely irrelevant if the question is valid.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "allocated".

Comment: @self., could be, but I don't see any added value in this question.

Comment: `static` variables are initialized exactly one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title says "Allocation and Initialization" and the question says "Allocation and declaration".

Either cases

This actually depends on the compiler implementation. If a variable is declared but never used, a smart compiler would produce a warning, and not allocate it at all on the stack.

An allocation means to provide space on the stack (or heap, if its `malloc`ed). Initialization means to assign a value to the variable. And Declaration tells the compiler that the variable exists. It could also mean the variable exists in some other object file if it is preceded by `extern`.

To answer your second question, again its compiler dependent.. if the compiler sees that the value of a variable does not change, then the `int x` would be allocated once. The allocation is basically shifting the call stack up a few notches to accommodate the data. And deallocation would be to shift the call stack down a few notches(or bytes if you prefer).

On the other hand, the `static int` is only allocated once, outside the stack storage area typically which will not let the variable be deallocated until the program finishes its execution.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the difference between allocation and intialisation?

- *allocation* is the action of taking – allocating – some memory for the variable ;
- *initalization* is the action of setting a value inside the allocated memory.

> How many times does the below variable x get allocated if there were an int?

```
for(j = 2; j < 20; j++){
   int x = 5;
   …
}
```

in that example, the variable `x` gets allocated 18 times, and deallocated at each iteration. Though a compiler might optimize and reuse that variable allocated space to spare a few cycles. And that variable gets initialized 18 times as well.

> and a static int?

```
for(j = 2; j < 20; j++){
   static int x = 5;
   …
}
```

The static variable `x` will be allocated once, and will never be deallocated, as the compiler can't tell if the function might get called again later in the program (even if it's obvious for the programmer). And the static variable will get only initialized once as well. To show off how a static variable behaves test the following program:

```
void foo() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        static int x = 5;
        printf("%d\n", x);
        x = 2;
    }
}

int main(){
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

which will produce one `5`, and 17 `2`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable x is declared inside the loop, its scope is only inside the loop. So the variable is destroyed everytime the controls finishes executing the loop. Then reinitialized when it reaches the body of the loop.

But when declared static, the initialization is done only once.